# How set padding (or margin) to android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout, but

Tags: android, drawerlayout

I have a list with many elements, and this list - in DrawerLayout.
Here http://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html - 
Vertical spacing - 8dp, that what me need.

How set padding or margin (8dp) to DrawerLayout, that after scroll down my list , this padding or margin be **scrolled** along with the list. Not be stayed always in on top ... (I want behaviour like scrolling items on ScroolViews)...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `padding="8dp"`, use `clipToPadding="false"`. The children views will be drawn on top of your padding when you scroll your listview.

Comment: Awesome answer. It s work, I spent all day for this problem, but it is very SIMPLE... I cant beleve it , Thank you